# Parse Error while using AutoDock Vina

Tags: database

I am trying to dock ligands with proteins to estimate the docking potential however, I am facing this error while docking. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: could you share the content of the line 574 of the Spike_C.pdbqt file? You can use `sed` for select one line after and one before of the 574 specific line  `sed -n '573,575p' Spike_C.pdbqt`

Comment: Could you also let us know how you converted your ligand to the PDBQT format (`prepare_ligand4.py`, obabel etc.)

Comment: Also (minor point), having the grid box the size of your protein (270_000 Å) is not a good idea: you may know where the ligand binds —i.e. receptor binding domain. In the case of a VLS you _want_ scores for it to bind there. Otherwise a lot will stick to the energetically unhappy transmembrane domain doing nothing.